# How to detect if a mouse pointer hits a line already drawn on an HTML 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseover

I am trying to figure out how one can detect if the user's mouse hits a line on an HTML 5 canvas with jQuery.

Here is the code that generates the canvas lines:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(40,0);
        ctx.lineTo(40,360);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.moveTo(80,400);
        ctx.lineTo(80,40);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.moveTo(120,0);
        ctx.lineTo(120,360);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.moveTo(160,400);
        ctx.lineTo(160,40);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
</script>
```

I'm using a modified jQuery script that I actually found in another question on here, but now I can't figure out how to detect the line, mainly the difference in color from white to black, in the canvas.  I know that this can be done with images, but I haven't seen anyone with something like this.

I guess my real question is, is there a way to detect color changes on a canvas element with jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its possible to do with javascript. In fact you aren't using any jQuery in your example above. An easy way to do it is by grabbing the pixel data from the canvas, and checking the alpha at the specified x and y position. If the alpha isn't set to 0, then you have something drawn on the canvas. Below is a function I put together real quick that does that.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/zzuYh/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 400;
height = 400;

canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;

// draw
ctx.moveTo(40, 0);
ctx.lineTo(40, 360);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(80, 400);
ctx.lineTo(80, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(120, 0);
ctx.lineTo(120, 360);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(160, 400);
ctx.lineTo(160, 40);
ctx.stroke();

function detectLine(x, y) {
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        inputData = imageData.data,
        pData = (~~x + (~~y * width)) * 4;

    if (inputData[pData + 3]) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    var x  = e.pageX,
        y = e.pageY;
    console.log(detectLine(x, y));
});

console.log(detectLine(40, 100));
console.log(detectLine(200, 200));
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  I did have jQuery code in my original code on my computer, but realized that the way I was doing it would only work if I had an image in `canvas` which is why I posted this question.